# JPEG RAW images not displaying in Safari on MacOS Sierra or iOS 10

Tags: safari, jpeg, ios10, macos-sierra

We've recently had some users of our app report that JPEG images aren't displaying properly since they updated to iOS 10.

We've looked into it and found that some JPEG images do work OK, and some don't. There are no errors logged anywhere.

The ones that don't work in our app also don't work in Safari on iOS 10. Not only that, but they also don't work in Safari on MacOS Sierra.

So we've checked the files themselves out and found that the files that don't work begin `ÿØÿÛ`, while the others that *do* work OK begin `ÿØÿá`.

Googling these signatures led us to this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Here it states that the images that aren't working are *JPEG Raw*, as opposed to `JFIF` or `Exif` format JPEGs.

So the question is: Why does this no longer work, and what's the best solution to work around it? I don't want to have to re-encode the images because of the lossy nature of JPEGs. We also can't get the source of these images to change, unfortunately.

We've considered a solution for our app, but that won't solve the problem in Safari.

There's always the wonder of *why have Apple removed support for this format?*